# Looking for the name of an anime

Tags: story-identification, anime

The only thing I can remeber and I cant find it online was in the beginning the girl mc was driving around with others and is attacked by these monsters. A short amount of time into the fight a kid who is half human and half monster (same as the ones who attacked the main character) saves the girl by killing the monster. I believe he made like a sword out of his arms or was just really powerful but I could tell he could make his arm into a number of useful entities/tools. If anyone knows the name of this anime, please answer as I really want to rewatch it fully.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)

Comment: Ok can you give more info.  How did they look, how long ago did you watched it? More description on the monsters.

Comment: It could also help potential answerers to notice it as a question that rings a bell, if you put details in the post title itself beyond "Looking for the name of an anime". I suggest something like "Anime ID: half-monster kid who can turn his arm into sword saves girl from monsters that attacked her car".

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it fits, but could it be [Blue seed](https://myanimelist.net/anime/998/Blue_Seed)? There's not much information to go on to be sure, though.

[image: Mamoru The Half-monster]

Comment: Can you explain why this matches?

Comment: the chased girl, the guy half-monster that protects hers. still not too much info to go on about